# Integrate Metamask into my own app

Tags: metamask

I would like to know if there is a way to integrate Metamask as a wallet directly into my own app. This can be downloaded from the App Store and does not require an additional Metamask mobile app. Nevertheless, the security standards of Metamask can be used through the API connection in my app. There you can import or create a wallet.

I need the information about the feasibility for my concept planning.

Thank you very much.
Kind regards
Joel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but suppose you were somehow able to do it - how do you prove to your end users that you don't copy their private key / seed phrase data?